# Configuration Menu Items

Tags: routes, 8

How can I add a section to the admin/config route and populate it with my own modules? In Drupal 7 it was easy, but I can't figure it out now in Drupal 8. The closest I can get is adding my modules to the Configuration Menu List that appears in the sidebar.

module.links.menu.yml

```
module.admin_settings:
  title: 'Module Admin Title'
  description: 'Module Admin Desc.'
  route_name: my_module.my_module_settings
  parent: system.admin_config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a menu link and a router item for the page:

1. Add a menu link in `my_module.links.menu.yml`. See [core/modules/system/system.links.menu.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.links.menu.yml/8):

   ```yaml
   my_module.my_group_menu:
     parent: system.admin_config
     route_name: my_module.my_group
   ```
2. Add a router item in `my_module.routing.yml`, which can re-use the same controller: [SystemController::systemAdminBlockPage()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!src!Controller!SystemController.php/function/SystemController%3A%3AsystemAdminMenuBlockPage/8). See [core/modules/system/system.routing.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!system.routing.yml/8) for an example.

   ```yaml
   my_module.my_group:
     path: '/admin/config/my-group'
   ```
3. Then add your menu link to your settings page as a parent to the menu link you created in #1.

Comment: Just I started Drupal8. So as u mentioned above parent: system.admin_config. If I used this I will get section name as CONFIGURATION bcz ts mentioned in that particular route. I want to create seperate section with my own choce of name. Is it possible or not. I dont want to use already defined route paths.

Comment: Yes, you would make the parent `my_module.admin_SECTION` and define a menu link for that as well and make its parent `system.admin`. Then make a corresponding route that is exactly like in system.routing.yml. See the answer above for all the respective links you need to look at for what I mentioned in this comment. If you have additional issues, post a new question and provide your routing and links.menu YAML files.

Comment: I have posted a new question please have a look at it. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237507/how-to-create-configuration-menu-in-drupal-8-with-selected-section-name

Answer (score 2):

You should assign your menu link to one of the specific groups on /admin/config by setting the correct path. You can find most of them in system.links.menu.yml and it usually matches the path, e.g. `parent: system.admin_config_media`.

Comment: But how would I add my own group, Berdir?

Comment: @EmGee – See @commonpike's answer below. You need to create a new parent route first, which calls `\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage`.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is right, but I found it hard to understand.

The sections on admin/config are actually a page. Take a look at the breadcrumbs after clicking on 'basic site settings': you can click `up` one level to a page for `system`.

So you need two links, and two routes. The first link defines a page you will rarely use, but also creates the block on the admin/config page.

mymodule.links.menu.yaml:

```
system.admin_config_mysite:
  route_name: system.admin_config_mysite
  parent: system.admin_config
  title: MySite Settings
  description: 'Configure MySite'
  weight: 100
  
mymodule.settings:
  title: 'MyModule Settings'
  parent: system.admin_config_mysite
  description: 'Settings for MyModule'
  route_name: mymodule.settings
  weight: 100
```

mymodule.routing.yml

```
system.admin_config_mysite:
  path: '/admin/config/mysite'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\system\Controller\SystemController::systemAdminMenuBlockPage'
    _title: 'MySite Settings'
    _title_context: 'mysite'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
    
mymodule.settings:
  path: '/admin/config/mysite/mymodule'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyModuleSettingsForm'
    _title: 'MyModule Settings'
    _title_context: 'mysite'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```