# How do I create a configuration menu with the selected section name?

Tags: routes

I want to create a menu in the admin section that is in the sitename/admin/config path.

As of now, I am doing this.

#### Routing file

```
custom_menu.adminmenu_section:
    path: '/admin/config/custommenu'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Drupal\custom_menu\Controller\CustomMenuController::content'
        _title: 'Custom Menu Configuration'
    requirements:
        _permission: 'administer site configuration'

custom_menu.admin_menu:
    path: '/admin/config/custommenu/customconf'
    defaults:
        _form: 'Drupal\custom_menu\Form\CustomMenuForm'
        _title: Custom Menu creation
    requirements:
        _permission: 'administer site configuration'
```

#### links.menu file

```
custom_menu.adminmenu_section:
    title: 'Configuration'
    description: 'Custom Menus Configuration section'    
    parent: system.admin
    route_name: custom_menu.adminmenu_section

custom_menu.admin_menu:
    title: 'Custom Menus Conf'
    description: 'Custom Menus Configuration section'
    parent: custom_menu.adminmenu_section
    route_name: custom_menu.admin_menu
```

This code is not creating a section in the `admin/config` path. But when I used  **parent: system.admin_config** that time I will get menu in the admin section but the section name will be `CONFIGURATION`. Because its title given in the `system.admin_config` route, but I don't want that name.

I want to create a section with separate name. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with your code and you just have to change two little things in your custom_menu.adminmenu_section. The rest is ok. See below:

**module.links.menu.yml**

```
custom_menu.adminmenu_section:
  title: 'Configuration' <= change this to your section name
  description: 'Custom Menus Configuration section'    
  parent: system.admin_config  <= change this to system.admin_config
  route_name: custom_menu.adminmenu_section
```

Comment: Ohh nice.. I got it now. But previously also i was giving Configuration in a lower letter only rite.. why that was not working? In system.admin_config its in a capital letter..

Comment: In configuration basic theme of drupal 8 the headlines are uppercase...